# Use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit to prove this.

Tags: calculus, limits

I know to how prove normal limits using the epsilon-delta definition, say:

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$$
But, there was a question on my textbook which I couldn't quite figure out to do, even though I've thought about it for a while I don't even know how to go about starting it.

Use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=0 \iff \lim_{x\to c} \left\vert f(x)\right\vert=0.$$

Could anyone help me with this, even a hint on where to start? Thank you in advance

Comment: This is quite simple if you just start out by writing both limits in terms of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Have you done that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $|f(x)| = |(|f(x)|)|$, then applied the definition of limit

Comment: (+1) It might even be clearer to say that $$|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=|f(x)|-0=\bigl||f(x)|-0\bigr|.$$